# PowerShell, why does CreationTime expect US date format while system has European date format?

Tags: powershell, date-time

I've digitised my old VHS tapes and it's now quite a lot of separate files. I want to set the filedates to the 'original' dates of the events, so that I can sort them chronologically.

This can be done with PowerShell using `CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime`, but there is something I do not understand. My system date format is European, so DD-MM-YYYY but `CreationTime` only accepts US date format so MM/DD/YYYY (same goes for `LastWriteTime`). See code below, it's PS v4.0 btw.

```
# This gives error message: Cannot convert value "31-12-1998" to type "System.DateTime"
(Get-ChildItem oud_en_nieuw_beijum.mpg).CreationTime = '31-12-1998'

# This works correctly
(Get-ChildItem oud_en_nieuw_beijum.mpg).CreationTime = '12/31/1998'

# This gives error message: Cannot convert value "12/31/1998" to type "System.DateTime"
Get-Date -Date '12/31/1998'

# This works correctly
Get-Date -Date '31-12-1998'
```

It seems that `CreationTime` and `Get-Date` use the opposite date formats? Is there some logic behind this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do now, is cast a string (the date) directly to a `datetime` object (The `CreationTime` Property)

If you cast a string to `datetime`, you can only use two formats, en-US Culture or ISO 8601 format (also known as japanese datetime format). Read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359053/why-does-powershell-always-use-us-culture-when-casting-to-datetime

So you have three options now:

- Use ISO Format: `(Get-ChildItem oud_en_nieuw_beijum.mpg).CreationTime = "1998-12-31"`
- Use en-US: `(Get-ChildItem oud_en_nieuw_beijum.mpg).CreationTime = "12/31/1998"`
- Parse: `(gci oud_en_nieuw_beijum.mpg).CreationTime = ([datetime]::Parse("31.12.1998"))`

if you `parse()` it, PowerShell will parse the string, with your local culture info, so that way it can handle "european format"

if you want to parse a culture info that's different from your local culture, you can just create a `[cultureinfo]` object and parse the date. e.g:

```
$dateString = '10.12.2018'
$frenchCulture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR')
# Parsing with French Culture
[datetime]::Parse($dateString, $frenchCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand but that doesn't explain why setting `CreationTime` with string requires US date format, while every other PS function accepts the system dateformat as string-date. Btw I can even simply use `[datetime]::Parse('31-12-1998')` without a culture setting that also works correctly.

Comment: I'm new to PS but okay I think I understand now. Btw I'll just use the "Japanese" date format, because that is unambiguous and always works. Using `.CreationTime = [datetime]'1998-12-31'` is the shortest and works correctly. :)

Comment: @BdR you don't even need `[datetime]`, you you can make it even shorter ;-). see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I used (Get-Item Filename.extension).CreationTime=("6 October 2020 17:47:22") and  it totally works.

Same thing if you use it for LastWriteTime and LastAccessTime.